Crash: A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate
I am dealing with some spontanious crashes at one of our customers.
I have a windows forms application running on dotnet 8 as a self contained application. The application also implements some parts in WPF and uses some WinAPI interop in some places as well as office interop, through from the reproduction I got the user is not using it in the moment of the crash.
There is some global exception handlers in place:

wrapped the whole program execution in a global try catch block and log the exceptions to the logfile
subscribed to Application.ThreadException and write to the logfile
subscribed to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and write to the logfile

None of those seem to be hit, as there is nothing about the crash in any of the logfiles.
I have also tried to use the environment variables to collect dump files:

DOTNET_DbgEnableMiniDump=1
DOTNET_DbgMiniDumpType=4
DOTNET_DbgMiniDumpName (some file path and name was set)

But also no dump file is created with this crash.
The only information there is, is from windows event viewer (program name has been replaced):
Application: program_name.exe
CoreCLR Version:8.0.123.58001
.NET Version:8.0.1
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast.
Message: A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Primitives!Windows.Win32.UI.WindowsAndMessaging.WNDPROC::Invoke'.
Stack:
   at Windows32.PInvoke.PeekMessage(Windows.Win32.UI.WindowsAndMessaging.MSG*,Windows.Win32.Foundation.HWND,UInt32,UInt32,Windows.Win32.UI.WindowsAndMessaging.PEEK_MESSAGE_REMOVE_TYPE)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.Microsoft.Office.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(UIntPtr,Microsoft.Office.msoloop,Void*)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Microsoft.Office.msoloop,System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Microsoft.Office.msoloop,System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at GUI.Program.Main(System.String[])

Currently I don't know how I could get more information about the issue or what it could be. Why are the dump files not created? What other ways do I have to understand where the issue comes from?

Somewhere in your program, you passed a pointer to a .NET function to some native code (Windows, Office, etc). That native code is calling back but when it does, the .NET function has been collected or moved in memory (that's why .NET is called "managed") and you get this error. Review all places where you pass a pointer to a .NET function and put that function in a static variable (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097235/is-it-necessary-to-gchandle-alloc-each-callback-in-a-class) or use GCHandle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/44ey4b32(v=vs.100)

A catastrophic failure caused a call to FailFast. As you can see, this bypasses all error reporting and writes directly to the System Event log. These issues are difficult to debug, because the cause is not described. Some generators are native functions that accept a SafeHandle, and there's no GC.KeepAlive after the call; an event delegate is created to marshal callbacks, but there's no GCHandle.Alloc() for it; a WNDCLASSEXW is created to handle the callbacks, but the lpfnWndProc member is not pinned, etc.

Other stuff that comes to mind: you have a window of some sort that creates the MS Office Interop, then this window is destroyed for some reason. Or, you're trying to embed a MS Office window in a window of your own app

If you call an unmanaged function and this function returns -before- the callback has been used. Then the garbage collector can reclaim the callback since as far as .Net is concerned : it doesn’t exist at all it can garbage collect it.
There’s multiple ways you can go about it.

if your callback can be a static function then you can follow the unmanaged caller example.
If it can’t be static, (say you have a bunch of runtime arguments). Then while the callback will not be garbage collected when pinvoked, it can be garbage collected -after- the function returns. The arguments you pass to the pinvoked function definitely can be collected as well. So if you got some state class passed as an argument, you need to preserve them from being garbage collected through a GCHandle.

Unfortunately it’ll be tough to debug without knowing what exactly has been garbage collected. I suggest creating a GCHandle to the delegate then freeing it after the delegate has been called if the delegate is a callback called.

In case 2, GC.KeepAlive on the managed delegate, placed at a point where the callback will definitely have finished, should be enough
